# confirm current password in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i am trying to make a website using php with mysql database..
here is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
$query = "INSERT INTO tblSecurity Values('".$_POST['txtUser']."','".$_POST['txtPass']."')";
$password = $_POST['txtPass'];
$confirm = $_POST['txtPassConfrm'];
mysql_query($query, $con);
if($password = $confirm)
{

Header("Location: Login.php");
}
else
{
echo"Verify your Answer";
}
?>
```

the problem is, how can i verify if the confirm password is same with the password inputted, this code works but it wont move to `ELSE` even the passwords are not the same. can anyone help me correct this please.. thanks

Comment: `if($password = $confirm)` should be `if($password == $confirm)`

Comment: thanks sir. it help me verifying the password. but the problem now has change. even wrong password the 'user' and 'pass' have its values in my database;

Comment: The code you've provided is for adding fields into the database; there's nothing in there to check logins.

Comment: nevermind sir. i already solved the problem. thanks a lot

Comment: Also, avoid using `mysql_*` functions since they are deprecated. Switch to `mysqli_*` instead or use PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: i will sir, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

better practice is check two passwords are same in inputting stage.
here also code is correct , only mistake is php needs == instead of =.